# How to set flexible width of View in Size Classes iOS

Tags: ios, interface-builder, size-classes

[image]
I have a view that is embeded in a `UITableViewCell`. I want to run that TableView on both - iPhones and iPads. I have designed it in Interface Builder. It seems to work good on iPhones in preview but on iPad it does not expand to full width of the view. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The table view and its cell's constraint are working fine- it is clearly visible in the provided pic.

The black color view which is inside the tableview cell might have improper  constraints. Please check the constraints for that specific view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constraints for the view that is embedded in your UITableViewCell.

Just select that view then select "Pin" then

1. Uncheck "Constraint to margins"
2. Select all red dotted line(top,left,below,right)
3. Tap on add 4 constraints.

Then run your app in iPad device.